# Show image for a very short time

Tags: c#, image

We're going to do some experiments on perceptual thresholds and want to show an image for a very short time. I'm speaking about less then 10 ms (our screen supports 144 Hz, that is a new image every 6.94 ms).

But all our approaches until now failed. We tried it with C#: WinForms were much too slow, WPF was faster, but we were still able to see the image, and even showing a texture with XNA framework did not work for us.

Do you have any suggestions for us? We're allowed to use C++ too, but we prefer using C#, so if your suggestions works with C# we would really much appreciate.

Comment: [Similar question which might give you a decent approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811165/continuous-image-swap-while-mouse-is-hovering)

Comment: Are you rendering in a back frame?  By this I mean, do you render the image in an invisible state then show it/hide it?  It seems that you should be able to do this in most languages if you do.

Comment: How did you implement this in WinForms?

Comment: How did you measure its speed to know its not fast enough?
Did you use fullscreen? what resolution?

My solution would be a small-resolution fullscreen image(dont forget to change the refresh rate to the max!) with atomic clock timings(I would implement that with OpenCL)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @KingCronus: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @akaltar: This is one of our major problems: we don't have any idea how to measure this. We had a discussion yesterday and pointed out that the monitor itself may be the weakest link in the chain (btw: is this phrase commonly used in English?) as the graphics card output is not synced to the monitor and the image may be shown for more than one monitor refresh. I hope you understand what I mean...

Comment: @ghummelll Well... for measurement I dont realy have an idea..
But a few things I suggest Is to use some good-quality display(perhaps some plasma with 600Hz refresh rate). and make sure that the settings in the OS and the program use high refresh-rate.Also make sure that the cap isnt in the program either, so make its loop small. nothing else I can think of.(I dont know if that phrase is used in english, but i think there is such a TV show so i guess yes)

Comment: "WPF was faster, but we were still able to see the image" - OK, but are you sure it was visible for longer than 6.94ms? Perhaps that's within human limits depending on the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using the XNA Framework for this. Some might consider it overkill but the fact is it is first of all designed to handle high throughput of frames and secondly has a relatively small learning curve.

I'm not a game developer but started by reading an article, modifying a simple project and creating one from scratch.

This would probably be your best bet in terms of the technologies you mentioned in your question.

**UPDATE:** Regarding measuring the actual time an image is shown, XNA would again be your closest guess short of dealing with specialized hardware and resorting to low-level programming.